# Firefox download popup freeze

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, freeze

I've recently installed a fresh xubuntu and I'm having a strange bug on `firefox:65.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` (it was already there in the preceding version `64.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`)

Every time I download a file, even if it's a tiny tiny file, when the download popup appears to choose the destination and accept the download, the whole firefox process freezes for about 5 seconds waiting for something in the background, and then only I can accept (or not) the download and keep browsing.

EDIT: Actually it doesn't fully freeze, it's just ultra laggy, and display gets weird if I try to move the pop-up.

What I've tried:

- I've tried uninstalling with `apt purge firefox` but for some reasons all my tabs, bookmarks, config and extensions were still there after reinstalling
- I've tried to then check all files used by firefox with `dpkg -L firefox` but some must be missing because I didn't see any config files left but still, my config was still there after reinstalling
- So I thought okay whatever, this may be caused by an extension or some options so I tried disabling all extensions -> no change
- I've tried disabling hardware acceleration in options (after all I'm not sure what it does so why not try it out) -> no change
- I ran `apt policy firefox` and tried downgrading to the only other version in the ubuntu bionic repositories : `firefox:59.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1` -> it just crashes when starting the program

At this point my lack of sys skills (even configs resist me and won't get deleted wth) tells me to ask for help because I don't really know what's the problem and where to look for.
I could try to manually install older versions of firefox but if I could fix this problem while staying with an up-to-date browser that would definitely be a plus.

Thanks for any help you could provide.

EDIT2: Running firefox from the shell gives no meaningfull errors when the bug occurs. I've seen there is an option to run firefox in debug mode in gdb but I'm not sure I want to try and look for the error there, maybe later.

Comment: Steps to be followed: Close all Firefox window, rename `~/.mozilla` folder, open Firefox. Any change?

Comment: This makes sense that the user-specific config is there indeed, thanks for pointing it out. So my config was indeed reset (renaming the folder back to its original name didn't even bring back the config) but the bug is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution.
I did downgrade my firefox but for the Extended Support Release : https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/

> Firefox ESR does not come with the latest features but it has the
>   latest security and stability fixes

Seems good enough for me.
If you have any idea what caused this bug, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was only my Firefox, but everybody is having the same problem. Take a look at this:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1517101

They say that it is already fixed for Firefox 66, but it is still in beta version.
Then another option we have is to install the beta version. I followed [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/how-to-install-firefox-beta-or-nightly.html) instructions to install the beta and it worked flawlessly. If you choose to install it too, please confirm here it also works for you.